# What is the asymptotic running time of this nested loop?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I'm trying to figure out the asymptotic running time of a function that calculates the value of k^n, where k and n are integers:

```java
int Foo(k, n)
{
  exp = 1;                     //constant time
  for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){     //n times
    newexp = 0;                //constant time
    for(int j=0; j<=k; j++)    //n*k times
      newexp = newexp + exp;   //constant time
    exp = newexp;              //constant time
  }
  return(exp);                 //constant time
}
```

As *k* and *n* become sufficiently large, does the running time become O(n+k)?

Comment: The outer loop runs `n` times. The inner loop runs `k` times for each one the outer one does. How many times does the inner loop run?

Comment: That is a big-O notation and you have tagged it as big-theta and little-o.  If you dont understand the terms or concept try taking online courses. It is too mundane a question for stackoverflow.

Comment: I suppose adding infinities will get you the same result as multiplying them.

Comment: Your comments should be improved to reflect the nesting of the loops. It is not the "header" of a loop that is executed that many times, it is the whole loop, body inclusive. By the way, `+1`, not `-1`. And by the way again, the function computes (k+1)^(n+1) !

Comment: Also, O(n) + O(k) makes no sense; O(n+k) would. And big-O does **not** mean that k and/or n go to infinity, that's completely wrong. It means that k and/or n are "sufficiently large".

Comment: Saying the terms go to infinity is quite common. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition. What definitions say we write "f = O(g(n)) for sufficiently large n" instead of "f = O(g(n)) as n -> Inf"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the complexity of the nested loops is computed as their product not as a sum. If n and k are inputs (not constants) then complexity is O(nk) if one of them is a constant lets say k is a constant then complexity is O(n)